# Why can't I use 'sudo su' within a shell script? How to make a shell script run with sudo automatically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

I cannot figure out what's wrong with this. When I run it in terminal and enter password, nothing happens, but if I run every command separately in terminal, it works. Thank you!

```
#!/bin/bash    

sudo su;
mkdir /opt/D3GO/;
cp `pwd`/D3GO /opt/D3GO/;
cp `pwd`/D3GO.png /opt/D3GO/;
cp `pwd`/D3GO.desktop /usr/share/applications/;
chmod +x /opt/D3GO/D3GO
```

Comment: As an aside, `"$PWD"` is **much** more efficient to evaluate than `$(pwd)` or its backtick equivalent; every time you run a command substitution you're `fork()`ing off a subprocess, running the given command (in this case `pwd`) in that separate process, and then reading its output over a pipeline; whereas `$PWD` is evaluated in the parent shell directly.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Command `sudo su` starts an interactive root shell, but it will not convert the current shell into a root one.

The idiom to do what you want is something along the lines of this (thanks to @CharlesDuffy for the extra carefulness):

```
#check for root
UID=$(id -u)
if [ x$UID != x0 ] 
then
    #Beware of how you compose the command
    printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$0" "$@"
    exec sudo su -c "$cmd_str"
fi

#I am root
mkdir /opt/D3GO/
#and the rest of your commands
```

The idea is to check whether the current user is root, and if not, re-run the same command with `su`

Comment: `"$0 $@"` is not right -- breaks horribly with whitespace, glob characters, etc, because it's trying to flatten `$@` (an array) into a string. `printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$0" "$@"; exec sudo su -c "$cmd_str"` would be closer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Well, I think you are right, the arguments are expanded twice. I guess you are never careful enough with root scripts.

Comment: (While nitpicking, by the way -- the `[ x$foo = xbar ]` practice isn't needed in any POSIX.2-compatible shell -- it's a holdout from the Bourne days -- but if you want some correctness-related paranoia, you should really quote: `[ "$UID" != 0 ]`; otherwise, even with the `x`s you'll get syntax errors if your expanded string splits into multiple words... which can even happen for `$UID` if your `IFS` contains numeric characters).

Comment: This works, @rodrigo could you update the answer if Charle's solution is better, because I'm very new with scripts.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I like nitpicking as much as anyone... I copied this command from an embedded system of mine where the `x` is needed. And about the arguments, since they are not needed by the OP, they could be dropped altogether, but the `$0` is still expanded twice (what if your script is named `*`?)

Comment: @DusanMilosevic, ...by the way, since this approach trusts `$0` to be correct, it's at least somewhat potentially error-prone. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028 for an in-depth discussion.

Comment: @rodrigo, are you sure the `x`s were *really* needed? If you weren't quoting (and, after all, you didn't quote here), you'd see errors in the empty-string case... but adding the `x`s *only* fixes the empty-string case, whereas adding quotes fixes both the empty-string case and the multiple-words case.

Comment: @rodrigo, ...I say that being familiar with the shells used in modern embedded systems; they're mostly `ash` derivatives, which are in fact compliant with POSIX.2.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: What about `printf -v cmd_str "'%q' " "$0" "$@"`, With the extra `''` in the format string? Wouldn't that be better?

Comment: @rodrigo, no, it would not. `printf %q` is responsible for emitting a string which can be safely eval'd exactly as-is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Oh!, the `%q` takes care of everthing. Sweet.

Comment: I have added `mkdir ~/.D3GO/; 
cp -a `pwd`/viewright_backup/. ~/.D3GO/` These commands, and it doesn't work. The ./D3GO folder is not created. Do you know why? Thank you so much!

Comment: @DusanMilosevic: Use `$HOME` instead of `~`. Probably you have the directory created under `/root` instead of your user home.

Comment: Nope, it still creates a folder in root. But thanks, now, when I know that, I know what to do. Thanks!

Comment: Nicely done; taking full advantage of `bash` features and replacing `sudo su -c` with `sudo -s`, the solution can be simplified to `[[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]] || exec sudo -s "$BASH_SOURCE" $(printf '%q ' "$@")`

Answer (score 21):

You can use [Here Documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to redirect input into an interactive shell script. The operator `<<` is an instruction to read input until it finds a line containing the specified delimiter, as `EOF` (end of file).

```
sudo su <<EOF
echo "code"
EOF
```

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash    
sudo su <<EOF
mkdir /opt/D3GO/
cp `pwd`/D3GO /opt/D3GO/
cp `pwd`/D3GO.png /opt/D3GO/
cp `pwd`/D3GO.desktop /usr/share/applications/
chmod +x /opt/D3GO/D3GO
EOF
```

Answer (score 10):

`sudo su` is not a command run within a shell -- it *starts a new shell*.

That new shell is no longer running your script, and the old shell that *is* running the script waits for the new one to exit before it continues.

Comment: And is it possible to prompt the user for password then?

Comment: `sudo` and `su` typically support prompting directly to the TTY.

Answer (score 9):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640403/45375) works well, but  the **idiom for a script re-invoking itself with `sudo` on demand** can be **simplified** and made **more portable**:

```
[[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]] || exec sudo /bin/bash -c "$(printf '%q ' "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@")"
```

- Using `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` makes prepending `x` to the operands (or double-quoting the LHS) unnecessary.
- Using `bash -c` instead of `su -c` to interpret the reconstructed command line makes the command more portable, because not all platforms support `su -c` (e.g., macOS doesn't).
- In `bash`, `$BASH_SOURCE` is generally the more reliable way to refer to the running script.

---

With the above approach, any variable references or command / arithmetic substitutions in the arguments are invariably expanded by the *calling* shell.

If you instead you wanted ***delayed* expansion** - so that variable references aren't expanded until the `sudo` shell runs, in the context of the *root* user - use this:

```
(( __reinvoked )) || exec sudo -s __reinvoked=1 "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
```

Note that you'd then have to *single*-quote any arguments containing variable references or command substitutions for them to be delayed-expanded; e.g., `'$USER'`.

Note the use of ad-hoc environment variable `__reinvoked` to ensure re-invocation *exactly once* (even when initially already invoked as the root user).

---

Here's a **sample script** that demonstrates the first technique:

- If not invoked as root, the script reinvokes itself with `sudo -s`, passing all arguments through as-is.
- Unless previously authenticated and still within the timeout period, `sudo` will prompt for an administrator password.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]] || exec sudo /bin/bash -c "$(printf '%q ' "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@")"

# Print the username and all arguments.
echo "Running as: $(id -un)"
echo "Arguments:"
for arg; do echo "  $((++i)): [$arg]"; done
```

---

[acfreitas's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30628060/45375) demonstrates a **"script-inside-a-script" technique** where a **here-document** is used to provide shell code via stdin to `sudo su`.
Again, **`sudo -s` is sufficient** and **quoting is important**:

```
sudo -s -H <<'EOF'
echo "$HOME"
EOF
```

Note how the opening here-document delimiter, `EOF` in this case, is *quoted* in order to prevent the contents of the document from *up-front* interpretation by the *current* shell.
If you didn't quote (any part of) `EOF`, `$HOME` would be expand to the *current* user's home directory.

If you want to ***mix* up-front and delayed expansion**, leave the opening here-document delimiter *unquoted* and selectively `\`-quote `$` instances:

```
sudo -s -H <<EOF
echo "Called by: $USER; root's home dir: \$HOME"
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Because running "sudo su" opens a new shell and the command does not return until you exit from that shell.  Perhaps split the script into 2 files: first one runs sudo and executes that 2nd script under sudo.

Answer (score 2):

sudo su will attempt to start a new shell as root.
Once that new shell is opened, the original script will not continue until the new shell is closed.

For a fix try:

In the shell script try:

```
su <username> -c "my command"
```

So if the user was "userA":

```
su userA -c "mkdir /opt/D3GO/"
```

However, if you are userA for example and you want to run the part of script as root, you will be prompted for a pass.

```
su root -c "mkdir /opt/D3GO/"
```

You can also get around that by just running the script with sudo in the first place

```
sudo ./myScript.sh
```

That way the script retains the original user inside the script which you can access using the standard variables like ***${USERNAME}***, ***${UID}*** etc

Depends on what works better for you.

Comment: `su root` in the script also opened up the Password prompt for me