# Pass commands as input to another command (su, ssh, sh, etc)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, sh

I have a script where I need to start a command, then pass some additional commands *as commands* to that command.  I tried

```
su
echo I should be root now:
who am I
exit
echo done.
```

... but it doesn't work: The `su` succeeds, but then the command prompt is just staring at me.  If I type `exit` at the prompt, the `echo` and `who am i` etc start executing!  And the `echo done.` doesn't get executed at all.

Similarly, I need for this to work over `ssh`:

```
ssh remotehost
# this should run under my account on remotehost
su
## this should run as root on remotehost
whoami
exit
## back
exit
# back
```

How do I solve this?

> I am looking for answers which solve this in a general fashion, and which are not specific to `su` or `ssh` in particular.  The intent is for this question to become a [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) for this particular pattern.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758235/how-to-execute-a-group-of-commands-as-another-user-in-bash

Comment: Why don't you make a `shell-script` with the commands you want to run as root? Then all you would have to do is run `sudo sh yourshellscript.sh`.

Comment: @JoseSerodio That would not work for the `ssh` scenario, for example (or you would have to `scp` the script to the remote host first), and unattractively complicates the simple case when the commands are just a few trivial ones (then you have to manage two script files, and make sure the calling script knows the path to the other one). And of course it doesn't easily extend to scenarios where some commands are dynamic (conditional on computing performed in the calling script, for example).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A shell script is a sequence of commands.  The shell will read the script file, and execute those commands one after the other.

In the usual case, there are no surprises here; but a frequent beginner error is assuming that *some* commands will take over from the shell, and start executing the following commands in the script file instead of the shell which is currently running this script.  But that's not how it works.

Basically, scripts work *exactly* like interactive commands, but how *exactly* they work needs to be properly understood. Interactively, the shell reads a command (from [standard input](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Descriptors)), runs that command (with input from standard input), and when it's done, it reads another command (from standard input).

Now, when executing a script, *standard input is still the terminal* (unless you used a redirection) but the commands are read from the script file, not from standard input. (The opposite would be very cumbersome indeed - any `read` would consume the next line of the script, `cat` would slurp all the rest of the script, and there would be no way to interact with it!) The script file *only* contains commands for the shell instance which executes it (though you can of course still use a [here document](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) etc to embed inputs as command arguments).

In other words, these "misunderstood" commands (`su`, `ssh`, `sh`, `sudo`, `bash` etc) when run alone (without arguments) will start an interactive shell, and in an interactive session, that's obviously fine; but when run from a script, that's very often not what you want.

All of these commands have ways to accept commands by ways other than in an interactive terminal session.  Typically, each command supports a way to pass it commands as options or arguments:

```
su root -c 'who am i'
ssh user@remote uname -a
sh -c 'who am i; echo success'
```

Many of these commands will also accept commands on standard input:

```
printf 'uname -a; who am i; uptime' | su
printf 'uname -a; who am i; uptime' | ssh user@remote
printf 'uname -a; who am i; uptime' | sh
```

which also conveniently allows you to use here documents:

```
ssh user@remote <<'____HERE'
    uname -a
    who am i
    uptime
____HERE

sh <<'____HERE'
    uname -a
    who am i
    uptime
____HERE
```

For commands which accept a single command argument, that command can be `sh` or `bash` with multiple commands:

```
sudo sh -c 'uname -a; who am i; uptime'
```

As an aside, you generally don't need an explicit `exit` because the command will terminate anyway when it has executed the script (sequence of commands) you passed in for execution.

Comment: Wouldn't `a | ssh ..@...` just pass stdin to a command on server side, so `a | ssh ...@... 'sh'` is needed.

Comment: @andlrc No, it's not needed. In the absence of an explicit command, `ssh` runs a shell.

Comment: ... Though that will be the user's login shell, which is rarely `sh` these days.

Comment: The `script` command does not portably accept a command as a command-line argument, though Linux `script` has `script -c 'your command here'`

Answer (score 25):

Adding to [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37586820/6394138):

It is important to remember that the section of the script formatted as a here-document for another shell is executed in a different shell with its own environment (and maybe even on a different machine).

If that block of your script contains parameter expansion, command substitution, and/or arithmetic expansion, then you must use the here-document facility of the shell slightly differently, depending on where you want those expansions to be performed.

#### 1. All expansions performed within the scope of the parent shell

The delimiter of the here document must be **unquoted**.

```
command <<DELIMITER
...
DELIMITER
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
mylogin=$(whoami)
sudo sh <<END
    a=1
    mylogin=$(whoami)
    echo a=$a
    echo mylogin=$mylogin
END
echo a=$a
echo mylogin=$mylogin
```

Output:

```
a=0
mylogin=leon
a=0
mylogin=leon
```

#### 2. All expansions performed within the scope of the child shell

The delimiter of the here document must be **quoted**.

```
command <<'DELIMITER'
...
DELIMITER
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
mylogin=$(whoami)
sudo sh <<'END'
    a=1
    mylogin=$(whoami)
    echo a=$a
    echo mylogin=$mylogin
END
echo a=$a
echo mylogin=$mylogin
```

Output:

```
a=1
mylogin=root
a=0
mylogin=leon
```

#### 3. Some expansions performed in the parent shell, some in the child

The delimiter of the here document must be **unquoted** and you must **escape the expansion expressions that are to be performed in the child shell**.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
mylogin=$(whoami)
sudo sh <<END
    a=1
    mylogin=\$(whoami)
    echo a=$a
    echo mylogin=\$mylogin
END
echo a=$a
echo mylogin=$mylogin
```

Output:

```
a=0
mylogin=root
a=0
mylogin=leon
```

Comment: This is particularly pesky for `ssh`, where you have to take both the remote and the local shell into account for quoting and escaping. So for example you need `ssh remote 'echo "\\"'` or `ssh remote "echo '\'"` or `ssh remote echo \\\\ ` to properly print a backslash on the remote host.

Answer (score 9):

**If you want a generic solution which will work for any kind of program, you can use the `expect` command.**

Extract from the manual page:

> **`Expect` *is  a program that "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script.***  Following the script, `Expect` *knows what can be expected from a program and what the correct response should be.  An interpreted language provides branching and high-level control structures  to  direct  the  dialogue.   In addition, the user can take control and interact directly when desired, afterward returning control to the script.*

Here is a working example using `expect`:

```
set timeout 60

spawn sudo su -

expect "*?assword" { send "*secretpassword*\r" }
send_user "I should be root now:"

expect "#" { send "whoami\r" }
expect "#" { send "exit\r" }
send_user "Done.\n"
exit
```

The script can then be launched with a simple command:

```
$ expect -f custom.script
```

You can view a full example in the following page: http://www.journaldev.com/1405/expect-script-example-for-ssh-and-su-login-and-running-commands

**Note:** The answer proposed by @tripleee would only work if standard input could be read once at the start of the command, or if a tty had been allocated, and won't work for any interactive program.

Example of errors if you use a pipe

```
echo "su whoami" |ssh remotehost
--> su: must be run from a terminal

echo "sudo whoami" |ssh remotehost
--> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

In SSH, you might force a TTY allocation with multiple `-t` parameters, but when `sudo` will ask for the password, it will fail.

Without the use of a program like `expect` any call to a function/program which might get information from stdin will make the next command fail:

```
ssh use@host <<'____HERE'
  echo "Enter your name:"
  read name
  echo "ok."
____HERE
--> The `echo "ok."` string will be passed to the "read" command
```

Comment: `expect` is a useful tool, and tangentially topical here, but as the answer to a simple shell syntax question, it's almost certainly overkill. In my 20+ years of shell programming, I have rarely needed to use it (and the availability of good general-purpose scripting languages like Perl, Python, Ruby etc makes it less necessary to ever learn).

Comment: Your question is simple, but the solution is not as long as you want it to be generic. The solution you proposed does not take into account that you can't push everything on `<stdin>` at the same time. But I agree with you, using `expect` is something we do not *expect* most of the time.