# Store output of grep command executed remotely using ssh to a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, grep

I am trying to run a series of commands on a remote server from a jenkins machine.
Those commands do below stuff

1. Create a directory on remote server
2. Copy some files from remote server into that directory

I have created below script,

```
    servername=<remote server ip>

    sshuserconnect() {
        echo `/usr/bin/sshpass -p passwd ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o UserKnownHostsFile=knownhosts -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $*`
    }

sshuserconnect user@$servername << ENDOFSSH

    sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF > /home/user/output.txt
    connect user/pwd@$servername:<port>/<DB schema>
    select column1||','||value from table where column1 like 'param1';
    EOF

    version=`grep version /home/user/output.txt | cut -f 2 -d ","`
    mkdir /home/user/${version}

ENDOFSSH
```

Script fails with below error,

```
grep: output.txt: No such file or directory
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

After some debugging I found out that script fails only for grep command. Assigning grep output to version variable fails.

I have tried lot of options and I am not if this is the correct way. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a simple typo to me. Note that you can use awk instead of `grep | cut`: `awk -F, '/version/ { print $2 }' output.txt`.

Comment: Two suggestions, change output.txt to ./output.txt in case the local directory isn't part of your PATH. Also change ${Version} to ${version}.

Comment: @LAROmega, I have edited the question and changed the file path to absolute path. still error remains same.
@TomFenech, I tried your approach as, `version='awk -F, '/version/ { print $2 }' /home/user/output.txt'`. still error is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script expansion of `` `grep version ...` `` is performed by the local shell rather than by the remote shell. The same applies to the expansion of `/home/user/${version}`. Subtleties of using expansions in here-documents are covered in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc/37746186#37746186) to [the canonical question addressing problems of this kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc).

Your script belongs to the mixed case "**3. Some expansions must be performed in the child shell, some - in the parent.**" discussed therein, and must be fixed as follows:

```
sshuserconnect user@$servername <<ENDOFSSH

sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF > /home/user/output.txt
connect user/pwd@$servername:<port>/<DB schema>
select column1||','||value from table where column1 like 'param1';
EOF

version=\$(grep version /home/user/output.txt | cut -f 2 -d ",")
mkdir /home/user/\${version}

ENDOFSSH
```

Note that I intentionally removed the indentation of the script section inside the `<<ENDOFSSH` here-document, so that `EOF` is correctly recognized as the end-marker for the nested `<<EOF` here-document. There are two ways to preserve the indentation:

1. Indent everything but the `EOF` end-marker:

   ```
   sshuserconnect user@$servername <<ENDOFSSH

       sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF > /home/user/output.txt
       connect user/pwd@$servername:<port>/<DB schema>
       select column1||','||value from table where column1 like 'param1';
   EOF

       version=\$(grep version /home/user/output.txt | cut -f 2 -d ",")
       mkdir /home/user/\${version}

   ENDOFSSH
   ```

   This looks somewhat ugly.
2. Indent **with TABs rather than spaces**, and use `<<-ENDOFSSH` instead of `<<ENDOFSSH`, which causes the leading tab characters in the here document to be removed. In the code below I purposefully marked the tab characters with `<TAB>`, both for explicitness and because StackOverflow renders tabs with spaces, meaning that copy&pasting the code would not work correctly:

   ```
   sshuserconnect user@$servername <<-ENDOFSSH

   <TAB>sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF > /home/user/output.txt
   <TAB>connect user/pwd@$servername:<port>/<DB schema>
   <TAB>select column1||','||value from table where column1 like 'param1';
   <TAB>EOF

   <TAB>version=\$(grep version /home/user/output.txt | cut -f 2 -d ",")
   <TAB>mkdir /home/user/\${version}

   ENDOFSSH
   ```

Comment: Good discussion, only nit is in *' Read this about'* the link `this` should be the *full title* (or at least a descriptive substring) of the article you are directing the user too.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the answer, though I couldn't find a good way of referring to the pointed-to question through its title.

Comment: Looks good, just something to make sure the users eyes don't skip over your link. Another trick is to **bold** the link.

Comment: Thanks Leon for your detailed answer. It gave me idea to rescript my work and avoid mistakes I was doing. I am able to run my script without errors now.