# Entering chroot, issue command, stay in chroot

Tags: linux, terminal, chroot

n00b question.

I have to issue a terminal command that will enter a chroot, issue a command (such as "ls"), and then stay in chroot so the user can type more commands.

Right now this is the best I've got:

```
cat << EOF | sudo chroot /path/to/chroot
ls
EOF
```

Unfortunately this exits the chroot as soon as it is finished though.

How can I stay in the chroot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass commands as input to another command (su, ssh, sh, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
sudo chroot /path/to/chroot sh -c "ls; bash"
```

This will run `ls` and then start an interactive `bash` shell.