# Get PID of the jobs submitted by nohup in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, pid, nohup

I'm using nohup to submit jobs in background in the machines I got through BSUB and ssh.

My primary machine is on `RHEL`, from there I am picking up other `AIX` machine by `BSUB`(Submits a job to LSF) and also doing a SSH login to another server.
After getting these two machines, executing a script(`inner.sh`) there through nohup.

I'm capturing the respective PIDs through `echo $$` in the script which I am executing(`inner.sh`).
After submitting the nohup execution in background, I am exiting both of the machines and landing back to primary RHEL machine.

Now, from this `RHEL` machine, I'm trying to get the status of the nohup execution by `ps -p PID` with the help of the previously captured two PIDs, but not getting any process listed.

Top level wrapper script **wrapper.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

#login to a remote server
ssh -k xyz@abc < env_setup.sh

#picking up a AIX machine form LSF
bsub -q night -Is ksh -i env_setup.sh

ps -p process-<AIX_machine>.pid
#got no output
ps -p process-<server_machine>.pid
#got no output
```

Script passed to Machines picked up by BSUB/SSH to execute nohup **env_setup.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup sh /path/to/dir/inner.sh > /path/to/dir/log-<hostname>.out &
exit
```

The actual script which I am trying to execute in machines picked up by BSUB/SSH **inner.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$ > /path/to/dir/process-<hostname>.pid
#hope this would give correct us the PID of the remote machine
#execute some other commands
```

Now, I am getting two `process-<hostname>.pid` files updated with two PIDs respectively each for both of the machines.

But `ps -p` at wrapper script is giving us no output.

I am picking up the process IDs from remote machines and doing `ps -p` at my local `RHEL` machine.

Is it the reason I am not getting any status update of those two processes?

Can I do anything else to get the status?

Comment: `ps` is running on your local machine, so you are just looking at it's processes. You'll have to `ssh` or `bsub` into the remote machine and `ps` there.

Comment: Are you expecting the commands after `ssh -k xyz@abc < env_setup.sh` to be running on `abc`? They're not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ps` give the status of local processes. `bsub` can be used to get the status of processes on each remote machine.

Comment: Is it possible to get status of the remote machines which are specifically picked up from my local machine by _bsub_?

Comment: bsub + ps: if inner script echoes hostname + pid, then bsub or ssh machine + ps -p pid, note that pid can be re-used, maybe there is a misconception but the question didn't give the context