# Bash Script: How to run command with $myVar as one of the arguments?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that SSHes into 2 machines and runs identical commands.

I'd like to store this in a var, but I'm not sure how to reference the contents of the var when running the command

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@123.123.123 -i ./travis/id_rsa <<-END
  sudo su;
  ...
  echo "Done!";
END


ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@456.456.456 -i ./travis/id_rsa <<-END
  sudo su;
  ...
  echo "Done!";
END
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
script=$(cat <<-END
  sudo su;
  ...
  echo "Done!";
END
)

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@123.123.123 -i ./travis/id_rsa $script
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@456.456.456 -i ./travis/id_rsa $script
```

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you hope for the variable to contain but at the very least you seem to be confused about how to use `su`. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc

Comment: Maybe you want `script='hostname; id'` and then `for host in 123.123.123 456.456.456; do  ssh -o etc etc ubuntu@"$host" sudo -s <<<"$script"; done`

Comment: `script=$(command)` assigns the standard output of `command` as the value of `script` so this seems like not at all what you want.

Comment: Also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like this:

```
cmds="sudo bash -c 'command1; command2; command3;'"
ssh ... "$cmds"
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wouldn't recommend it even in this case, especially without double-quotes around `$cmds`. Consider `cmds="sudo bash -c 'echo cp * /target/dir;'"` -- the `*` will get expanded to a list of files on the local computer before it's sent over ssh!

Comment: @GordonDavisson, oh, you're right -- I missed that the answer wasn't quoting the `"$cmds"` expansion. This is, indeed, bad practice even in the absence of variables substituted in when the command is assigned.

Comment: @JonasBjork, are you willing to [edit] your answer to correct that error?

Comment: It would be safer with regard to word splitting to use an array instead of a string.

Answer (score 2):

If I am at all able to understand what you are asking, you really *don't* want to put the commands in a variable.

```
for host in 123.123.123 456.456.456; do
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@"$host" -i ./travis/id_rsa<<-\____here
        sudo -s <<-_________there
            : your script goes here
________there
        echo "Done."
____here
done
```

If you really wanted to assign a multi-line variable (but trust me, you don't) the syntax for that is simply

```
script='sudo -s <<\____there
    : your commands
____there
echo "Done."'
```

But there really is no need to do this, andeit actually complicates things down the line. You see, passing in properly quoted strings as arguments to `ssh` is extremely tricky - you have the local shell and the remote shell and both require additional quoting or escaping in order to correctly pass through shell metacharacters; and the usual caveats with `eval` apply, only you are effectively running a hidden `eval` by way of passing in executable code as a string for the remote shell.