# how to run command line in linux from another user

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, splunk

I need to execute a bash script from a python program (python2.7) in red hat, while this bash script has to run from another user account as splunk user.

In the Linux, I will switch to splunk user `su - splunk` first, then type the command `./mybashFile` under as a splunk user

Here is what I tried:

```
import  subprocess
cmd1=subprocess.Popen(["su","-","splunk"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd2=subprocess.Popen(["./path/myBashFile.sh"],shell=True,stdin=cmd1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd2.stdout
```

I still cannot run this bash file from as a splunk user. This command cannot pass to another account.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc) for the fundamental reason why this can't work as posted

Answer (score 4):

`cmd1` and `cmd2` are two different processes and have no effect on each other. If you wanted to go the `su` route, you'd need to call you shell script through that:

```
...["su","-","splunk", "-c", "./path/myBashFile.sh"]...
```