# macOS - Switch to admin user when running a shell script as a root user

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, root

So, I have this name.sh script with bunch of shell commands.
I need to change the wallpaper before ending that script.

I'm using

```sh
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events.app" to set picture of every desktop to "/Library/Desktop Pictures/my.jpg"'
```

at the end of the line. The thing is the Apple Script won't run under root. Because System Events will throw 10810 at first and then 600 (Application isn't running). If I run this osascript under admin user, it will work just fine. The wallpaper will be set.

Let me know how you guys can help me in this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already `root`, you have full privileges to switch to a different user account at any time. The command for that is `su`.

If your user is `admin`,

```
su - admin <<\:
    osascript -e 'tell application "System Events.app" to set picture of every desktop to "/Library/Desktop Pictures/dneg.jpg"'
:
```

There are various ways to pass the command as standard input to `su`; perhaps see also [Pass commands as input to another command (su, ssh, sh, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc)