# Solve a permission problem found when running pgbackrest as a cron job

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, cron

I have a permissions error on a ubuntu host from the cron job setup to make a database backup using pgbackrest.

ERROR [041]: : unable to open /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/global/pg_control

The cron job is setup to run under my administrator account. The only option I see to fix this is to change the directory permissions to /var/lib/postgresql/10/main to allow my admin account in, and I don't want to do that.

Clearly only the postgres user has access to this directory and I found that its not possible to setup a cron job using that user.
i.e.

```
postgres@host110:~/$ crontab -e
You (postgres) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)
See crontab(1) for more information
```

What else can I do? There is no more information on this in the pgbackrest manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the PostgreSQL OS user (`postgres`) and its group are allowed to access the PostgreSQL data directory. See this code from [the source](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/init/miscinit.c;h=83c951485624a15f5fac49dff8790f6373c0ec7c;hb=refs/heads/REL_12_STABLE#l144):

```c
    /*
     * Check if the directory has correct permissions.  If not, reject.
     *
     * Only two possible modes are allowed, 0700 and 0750.  The latter mode
     * indicates that group read/execute should be allowed on all newly
     * created files and directories.
     *
     * XXX temporarily suppress check when on Windows, because there may not
     * be proper support for Unix-y file permissions.  Need to think of a
     * reasonable check to apply on Windows.
     */
#if !defined(WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
    if (stat_buf.st_mode & PG_MODE_MASK_GROUP)
        ereport(FATAL,
                (errcode(ERRCODE_OBJECT_NOT_IN_PREREQUISITE_STATE),
                 errmsg("data directory \"%s\" has invalid permissions",
                        DataDir),
                 errdetail("Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).")));
#endif
```

If the data directory allows the group in, the group will normally also have permissions for `pg_control`.

So you can allow that pgBackRest user in if you give it `postgres`' primary user group.

`postgres` is allowed to create a `crontab` if the system is configured accordingly.

From `man crontab`:

> Running `cron` jobs can be allowed or disallowed for different users.  For this purpose, use the `cron.allow` and `cron.deny` files.  If the `cron.allow` file exists, a
>   user must be listed in it to be allowed to use `cron` If the `cron.allow` file does not exist but the `cron.deny` file does exist, then a user must not  be  listed  in
>   the  `cron.deny`  file in order to use `cron`.  If neither of these files exists, only the super user is allowed to use `cron`.  Another way to restrict access to `cron`
>   is to use PAM authentication in `/etc/security/access.conf` to set up users, which are allowed or disallowed to use `crontab` or  modify  system  `cron`  jobs  in  the
>   `/etc/cron.d/` directory.

Comment: Yep. Added 'postgres' to cron.allow fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to `sudo -u postgres` at the prompt, you can do it in your `cron` job, too.

Your question doesn't reveal which actual commands you are trying to run, but to run `thiscommand` as `postgres`, simply

```
sudo -u postgres thiscommand
```

If you have `su` but not `sudo`, the adaptation is minor but not entirely trivial:

```
su -c thiscommand postgres
```

With `sudo` you can set fine-grained limitations on what exactly you can do as another user, so in that sense, it's safer than full unlimited `su`.

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc