# SMBClient from multiple ip

Tags: bash, libsmbclient

I would like to make a bash script where I read a list of IP addresses and run the following command:

```
smbclient \\\\ $ ip \\ ipc $ -U ". \ User" --pw-nt-hash
```

which does an exit and try with another IP, regardless of that it throws a message if the connection was successful, it does not execute with the IPs that are inside the list, it only tries with the first one in the list.

```sh
#/bin/bash 

IPLIST="ip"

for ip in $(cat ip)
do
   smbclient \\\\$ip\\C$ -U ".\user" --pw-nt-hash "user"
   exit
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the script to exit after the first `smbclient`, drop the `exit` command.

> smbclient \ $ ip \ ipc $ -U ". \ User" --pw-nt-hash, which does an exit

This `exit` is not done by `smbclient`, but rather by the script; therefore it ends.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that the `exit` gets passed as input to `smbclient`, but that's not how this works. You run `smbclient` and when it finishes, your script continues, and executes the `exit`.  See [Pass commands as input to another command (su, ssh, sh, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc) for a fuller discussion.

Also, [don't read lines with `for`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

```
#/bin/bash 

while read -r ip; do
   smbclient \\\\$ip\\C$ -U ".\user" --pw-nt-hash "user" <<<exit
done <ip
```