# How can I Executing Shell Commands with Python for restore database postgres?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I restore my database template on Linux as shown as:
Linux teminal:

```
su postgres
psql
create database test3;
\q
pg_restore -v -d test3 /opt/empty-db_template.backup
exit
systemctl restart postgresql-11.service
```

And done!. But when I  Executing Shell Commands in python as shown as Get stuck in `psql`step, How can I fix it?

[Get stuck in psql step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFTRh.png)

```
import os
os.system('ls')
os.system('su postgres')
os.system('psql')

os.system('create database test3;')
os.system('\q')


os.system('pg_restore -v -d test3 /opt/empty-db_template.backup')
os.system('exit')
os.system('systemctl restart postgresql-11.service')
```

Comment: you got os.system wrongly. It is not passing your strings as keystrokes, but executes argument as the command line.  So, for example, os.system('\q') does not have any sense. You should make all your operations as one command line. So you will have three os.system calls (one for 'ls', second for running psql and third to restart postgresql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `su postgres` switches to another user *and opens a subshell* wherein the following commands are executed.  In other words, you execute the commands (until the `exit`) as user `postgres`.

With the `os.system()` you leave the shell the `su` is opening at once.  The following commands are executed as your standard user again.

To avoid this, you will have to pass all commands to `su` directly as in

```
su postgres -c psql
```

And I take it that the line `create database test3` isn't a shell command but a line entered into the interactive `psql` command.  Then you will have to figure out how to do that non-interactively, e.g. by calling `psql -c 'create database test3'` or similar.  Consult the man page of `psql` for details.

So effectively you will use a line like

```
os.system('su postgres -c "psql -c \'create database test3\'"')
```

Quoting can be an issue.  Try around and if you don't succeed, open another question with more specific information on what you already tried.

Comment: Thanks help me, I create database:`os.system('su postgres -c "psql -c \'create database test3\'"')` and  restore my template: `os.system('su postgres -c "pg_restore -v -d test3 /opt/empty-db_template.backup" ')` and finish. Not need `os.system('\q')` and `os.system('exit')`

Comment: Yes, the `\q` will exit the interactive mode of postgres and the `exit` leaves the shell.  Both are obviously not necessary if you use the new approach.  Using `-c` to `su` terminates the shell after executing the command (so no `exit` needed) and calling `psql` with `-c` also executes one command and then terminates (so no `\q` needed).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here cannot work.  `su` creates a new shell.  It will be waiting for more input form the console.  You won't get the chance to enter the `psql` command until you have exited the `su` shell.  You either need to run this command as the `postgres` user, or use the `su` command repeatedly, or just create a shell script and run the shell script.

```
os.system( 'su postgres createdb test3' )
os.system( 'su postgres pg_restore ... ' )
os.systen( 'systemctl restart postgresql-11.service' )
```

Comment: In addition, you'll probably want to replace `os.system()` with `subprocess.run()` or one of its legacy precursors (in particular, `subprocess.check_call()`. You can get away with a single subprocess with `shell=True`, though you'll still need to figure out how to properly script these commands.