# one-liner to become another user and run a command as that user

Tags: sudo, switch-user

In my local machine, I would like to become another user (let's say currently I am `user_c`) and then to run a command as that user, specifically I would like to become `user_o` and run `whoami`.

I usually do this in two lines like so:

```
sudo -i -u -user_o         # Note: no password is needed to run this command
whoami
```

Now, how to do it one-liner?

I have tryed

```
sudo -i -u user_o && echo "$(whoami)"
```

but it just becomes `user_o`.

I have also tryed this

```
sudo -i -u user_o echo "$(whoami)"
```

but it just prints the current user, like it is ignoring the `sudo -i -u user_o` command

> ```
> user_c
> ```

also [runuser](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/runuser.1.html) does not work since `user_c` is not user `root` in my case:

> ```
> runuser -l user_o -c 'echo "$(whoami)"'
>
> runuser: may not be used by non-root users
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass commands as input to another command (su, ssh, sh, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

actually there is no need to use `&&` to separate the "switch user" command and the command that one wants to be executed as the target user.

```
sudo -i -u user_o whoami
```