Shell script - shh remote connection - need to press control C to execute touch commands
    #!/bin/bash
        if ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no userid@serverip 'df -h'; 
        then
          echo "Conn Success"
          array12=(
                  /home/uid/test
                  /home/uid/test1
                  /home/uid/test/ght
               )
    
         for dir in "${array12[@]}";do
            if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]]
            then
              touch "$dir/testfile123.txt"
            else
              echo "Failed to creat file under dir"
            fi
        done
       exit
    
    else
      echo "Failure to connect"
      exit
fi
          

I should press Ctrl C ,  df -h output is not displaying and then it is proceeding to create file under directories. Please suggest for modification.
I have tried this one also ssh -t -t userid@serverip 'df -h'; then

what is the result when you run ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no userid@serverip 'df -h' from command line?

As expected, output is displaying from command line:
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no userid@serverip 'df -h'

Fix your syntax errors first. Try https://www.shellcheck.net/

typo here, in actual script, no typos. I am wondering it is creating files under local system, not in remote system.

If your intent was to run these commands on the remote server, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc

As such, we don't know why running df -h remotely requires interaction from your side; it shouldn't. Do you have a login script which requires you to respond to a prompt or something? As such, that's not a programming topic, and would be suitable for [unix.se]; but they too will want more details about how your remote connection is set up.

ssh to remote host is working fine and df is displaying correctly.
if ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no userid@serverip 'df -h';
File creation through touch command is happening on local system, not on remote host
